# Fight outcome odds question

Tags: probability

I need to workout the odds of getting 5 fight outcomes correct using the following rules:

A fight is only correct when both the fighter and their method of victory is correctly chosen, each fight has 2 fighters and 3 methods of victory.

Winner -       FIGHTER A         FIGHTER B
Method -    Dec-Tko-Sub        Dec-Tko-Sub

All picks and outcomes are random.

To get the correct fighter is 1/2, then the chance of the correct method is 1/3.

Can somebody please work out the odds of getting:

1 fight correct (1/6?)
2 fights correct
3 fights correct
4 fights correct
5 fights correct

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is $\frac 16$ to get a fight correct.  Think about how you got that from $\frac 12$ to get the correct fighter and $\frac 13$ to get the method.  Now to get two fights correct, you have to do that twice in a row.  For more, more times.

Comment: Ok thanks for the guidance, but i am not sure how to work out the odds of getting 3 and 4 correct fight picks when there are 5 chances.

Comment: Do you mean getting 1 right out of 5?  I thought you were asking about getting 1 right out of 1, 2 out of 2, and so on.  If you want exactly 1 right out of 5 picks, it is not $\frac 16$.  If you have 5 fights, the number correct follows a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $p=\frac 16$